# Converting color photo to B&W on iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

My app takes a picture from the Library of the iPhone or the camera. Then there is a switch control to convert it to a B&W photo.

When I do the switch control, it doesn't do anything.

I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my code. I've looked at other examples on StackOverflow but couldn't get mine to work. Anyone see anything obvious?

Here is my Header file and below is my Implementation File.

```
//
//  ErdalKulguProjectViewController.h
//  ErdalKulguProject
//
//  Created by Kulgu, Erdal on 1/17/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ErdalKulguProjectViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *chosenImage;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *toggleCamera;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *toggleBlackWhite;


}

-(IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender;
- (UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *chosenImage;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UISwitch *toggleCamera; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) UISwitch *toggleBlackWhite;



@end
```

Implementation File:

```
//
//  ErdalKulguProjectViewController.m
//  ErdalKulguProject
//
//  Created by Kulgu, Erdal on 1/17/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ErdalKulguProjectViewController.h"

@implementation ErdalKulguProjectViewController

@synthesize chosenImage;
@synthesize toggleCamera; 
@synthesize toggleBlackWhite;
//@synthesize grayScale;


-(IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker; 
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];



    if ([toggleCamera isOn]) { 
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    } else { 
        imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    } 
    imagePicker.delegate=self; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; 
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
    [imagePicker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    chosenImage.image=[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];



}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}





- (UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Create image rectangle with current image width/height
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);


    if ([toggleBlackWhite isOn]) { 


    } else { 


    } 


    // Grayscale color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

    // Create bitmap content with current image size and grayscale colorspace
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, image.size.width, image.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

    // Draw image into current context, with specified rectangle
    // using previously defined context (with grayscale colorspace)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [image CGImage]);

    // Create bitmap image info from pixel data in current context
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    // Create a new UIImage object  
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    // Release colorspace, context and bitmap information
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CFRelease(imageRef);

    // Return the new grayscale image
    return newImage;
}





/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [chosenImage release];
    [toggleCamera release];
    [toggleBlackWhite release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: have you actually connected the switch to anything in interface builder? like ValueChanged Control event? I don't see such function in your code.

Comment: yes, i did that. I just dont know how to implement this code; - (UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image
{ do you know how to help me to go through this. i really need a help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your function actually works, you need to call it here:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    chosenImage.image=[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //adjust the image if switch is toggled
    if ([toggleBlackWhite isOn]) chosenImage = [self convertImageToGrayScale:chosenImage];
}
```

And then display the chosenImage.